# Java multithreading, weird things

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, concurrency

Alright so for fun I'm practicing multithreading and networking in Java right now but I've ran into something really weird. I have my code structure as follows. Client and Server are threads, which contain PacketListeners which are also threads that just add packets to a ConcurrentLinkedQueue when received.

My Server class looks like this

```
public Server(int port) {
        setThreadName("ServerThread");
        this.clients = new ArrayList<SocketAddress>();
        try {
            //this.socket = new DatagramSocket(null);
            //this.socket.setReuseAddress(true);
            //this.socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
            //this.socket.setReuseAddress(true);
            //this.socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
            //sender = new PacketSender(socket);
            this.listener = new PacketListener(port);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        listener.start();
    }

    synchronized private void processPacket(DatagramPacket packet) {
            if (packet != null) {
                String data = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
                System.out.println("Received a packet " + data);
                if (data.equalsIgnoreCase("connecting")) {
                    System.out.println("wut");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Packet from :" + packet.getAddress().toString() + " saying: " + data);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Packet == null");
            }
        }



        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("running server on port " + socket.getLocalPort());
            while (isRunning()) {
                if (listener.hasPacket()) {
                    System.out.println("listener has a packet");
                    processPacket(listener.getNextPacket());
                }
                sleep(1); // sleep for 1ms (keeps cpu usage from sky rocketing)
            }
        }
```

My PacketListener class looks like this

```
 public PacketListener(int port) throws IOException {
        this.socket = new DatagramSocket(null);
        this.socket.setReuseAddress(true);
        this.socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
        System.out.println("Packet listener bound @ " + socket.getLocalAddress() + " on port " + socket.getLocalPort());
        receivedPackets = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<DatagramPacket>();
    }

    synchronized private void addPacket(DatagramPacket packet) {
        if (!receivedPackets.add(packet)) {
            System.err.println("We dropped a packet because full queue");
        } else {
            System.out.println("We added a received packet! - " + receivedPackets.size());
        }
    }

    synchronized public boolean hasPacket() {
        return !receivedPackets.isEmpty();
    }

    synchronized public DatagramPacket getNextPacket() {
        return receivedPackets.poll();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
        DatagramPacket inPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        while (isRunning()) {
            try {
                socket.receive(inPacket);
                addPacket(inPacket);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the weird thing is that on the client end, say I send a few packets.
Let's say I send "hello", then "test1", then "test2"
The server will print out

```
Packet received
We added a received packet! - 1
listener has a packet

Packet received
Received a packet test1
We added a received packet! - 1
Packet from :/127.0.0.1 saying: test1
listener has a packet


Packet received
Received a packet test2
We added a received packet! - 1
Packet from :/127.0.0.1 saying: test2
listener has a packet
```

This should actually print out something along the lines of

```
We added a received packet! - 1
listener has a packet
Received a packet hello
Packet from :/127.0.0.1 saying: hello

We added a received packet! - 1
listener has a packet
Received a packet test1
Packet from :/127.0.0.1 saying: test1

We added a received packet! - 1
listener has a packet
Received a packet test2
Packet from :/127.0.0.1 saying: test2
```

Comment: What's weird?  What were you expecting to see?

Comment: Is that everything that it prints out? Are you really sending all 3 packets, "hello", "test1", and "test2"? Your output makes sense *if* you were sending "test1" *first*, and if following the print of the packet contents, your listener then prints "test2", etc.

Comment: I have the client set up so that I type in strings and it sends them to the server, which is what the server is receiving and printing. I also have the client verifying the packet data via prints before I send it. It should say something like 

    We added a received packet - 1
    listener has a packet
    Received a packet hello
    Packet from /127.0.0.1 saying: hello

and so on for all three

Comment: @CraigOtis is order of packets preserved with `DatagramSocket`s? `Multiple packets sent from one machine to another may be routed differently, and may arrive in any order.` from Javadocs.

Comment: It's not the order that's the problem. If you look at the processPacket method, for some reason it's just stopping mid method. Like it gets to the if statement, then only does it after another packet comes in.

Comment: @mostruash You're correct that order is not preserved - however I assumed that he was sending the packets manually, and I'm also assuming that since they're traveling to/from the same machine, a human-sized delay is more than enough time for them to arrive in the order he types them.

Comment: Having a fully working version will make things easier :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are reusing the same instance of DatagramPacket over and over again.

This means that one thread receive packets, but in reality it is only always "updating" the same instance of DatagramPacket. The queue will contain the same instance a few times.

The second thread is then pulling from the queue the same instance, that changes while the various print are being executed, so the printed result are erratic.

Moreover, i don't know the internals of the DatagramPacket class, but internal locks of synchronization could cause one thread to wait for the other or things like that.

Just to make sure there is no mutating stuff between the two threads, i would write :

```
    while (isRunning()) {
        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            DatagramPacket inPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            socket.receive(inPacket);
            addPacket(inPacket);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, I'll try changing that to see if it helps. I see what you're saying. I think you're on to something here, because I too don't think the DatagramSocket class is concurrent.

Comment: Hmm, so this did help a bit but still, the first packet sent causes the server to only print up to "listener has a packet". I don't get how that can be printed but the function that runs as soon as that is printed doesn't run?

Comment: The "new DatagramPacket" is still before the "while(isRunning())", and not inside it?

Comment: Just added the Server constructor for you to see.

Comment: Thank you. It works now. I'm not sure why that change fixed it though.

Comment: I think simply one thread was displaying a packet, and at the same time the packet changed, making the output messy and making it look like it was skipping some packets or receiving them in strange order.

Comment: That actually makes sense. I see it now. Sometimes I forget that behind the scenes, instances are just pointers, so when I just had that one instance it was just changing its value rather than adding new packets to the queue. Thanks again.